# UPSERT compatible with mySql and postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I've been googling and trying different queries but I haven't managed to get the UPSERT query to work with both mySql and postgreSql. Does anyone here know how to do it?

Comment: There isn't a syntax that is compatible between the two databases . . . unless you count doing a separate `UPDATE` and `INSERT` as a viable solution.

Comment: So if I am writing a program that requires it to work with both postgreSQL and mySQL how do I do?

Comment: Create and use stored procedures specific for each DBMS instead of edit data directly.

Answer (score 4):

There is not one, and cannot be one. PostgreSQL doesn't have an `UPSERT` statement. The new 9.5 statement `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE ...` is syntactically different from MySQL's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` because it's also *semantically* different, i.e. it works differently.

The newer PostgreSQL statement, added in 9.5, was designed with an awareness of MySQL's syntax. The decision not to use the same syntax was intentional because MySQL's statement has big ambiguities around handling of multiple unique indexes etc, where it basically shrugs and says "dunno".

You can possibly hide it behind stored functions, but really, this is why your application should be able to run different SQL on a different DBMS. Trying to always write one statement that works for all target DBMSes is a lost cause even if you're just targeting MySQL and PostgreSQL.